# Filtering an array of values by array of object's value

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, lodash

In Javascript we have an array:

```
let arr1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
```

...and an array of objects:

```
let arr2 = [ {name: "banana", id: 1},
             {name: "mango", id: 3} ];
```

I want to remove all the elements from `arr1` where `arr2`'s id = `arr1`'s value and return an array like this:

```
[2, 4, 5]
```

Here is what I've tried, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
let newArr = arr1.filter(
    x => !arr2.includes(e => e.id === x)
)
```

How can I achieve this? I can use `lodash` as well as ES6.

Comment: What is your attempt ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `.includes()` method doesn't allow you to pass a method into it to define equality. You can use [`.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) instead, which does allow you to specify this:

```js
const arr1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
const arr2 = [
  {name: "banana", id: 1},
  {name: "mango", id: 3}
];

const newArr = arr1.filter(x => !arr2.some(e => e.id === x))
console.log(newArr);
```

A more efficient approach would be to grab all the `id` properties from the objects in your array and put then in a [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) for quick look-up. Then use `.filter()` with `.has()` like so:

```js
const arr1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
const arr2 = [
  {name: "banana", id: 1},
  {name: "mango", id: 3}
];

const idSet = new Set(arr2.map(({id}) => id));
const newArr = arr1.filter(x => !idSet.has(x))
console.log(newArr);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can first create a temporary of *id* and *age*, then use `filter()` with `includes()`

```js
let arr1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
let arr2 = [ {name: "banana", id: 1},
         {name: "mango", age: 3} ];
let temp = arr2.map(i => i.id || i.age);
let res = arr1.filter(i => !temp.includes(i));
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let arr1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

let arr2 = [ {name: "banana", id: 1},
             {name: "mango", id: 3} ];

arr1.map((item,index) => 
  arr2.map(object => {
    if(item == object.id) arr1.splice(index,1)
  })
)

console.warn(arr1) /// output [2, 4, 5]
```